# How do I change a USB flash name from uppercase to uppercase and lowercase (mixed case)?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, rename

How do I change a USB flash name from uppercase to uppercase and lowercase (mixed case) ?

Comment: You have USB named, for example, MYUSBNAME and you want it to change to MyUsb, am I right? Are you using windows ?

Comment: yes , Windows 8.1

Comment: Can you format it ?

Comment: yes but the name always Uppercase

Answer (score 12):

You formatted it as FAT32 which will show as upper case in Windows Explorer.

Format it as NTFS or ExFAT & it will show in Windows as mixed case.
ExFat is more portable - most computers can read & write to it, natively [Mac & Windows, unix may need [additional drivers]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/create-and-format-exfat-partition-from-linux).

NTFS is native to Windows, though other OSes may be able to read & write to it using additional drivers [Mac can read but not write natively].

A quick Googling tells me some Samsung TVs can read NTFS, but not ExFAT [YMMV]. Also FAT32, but with the mentioned upper case on Windows naming & also a 4GB file size limit.

**FAT32**

[image]

**NTFS**

[image]

**ExFAT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks . can Samsung tv read file from exFAT format ? What is the allocation unit size ? and which is better for 16 Gb Flash ?

Comment: idk about a Samsung TV; would only take a couple of minutes to test. If uncertain, set Allocation unit size to 'Default' from the drop menu.

Comment: FAT32 is most compatible. Older TVs (couple years old) usually cannot read exFAT but understand FAT32; NTFS is rarely supported due to its complexity. Linux can use FAT32 but may not have exFAT out of the box due to patent issues, but you can install a kernel module or FUSE driver. NTFS is supported by Linux at least in read-only mode, write mode works but is not considered rock-solid. (Mac) OS X supports FAT32 / exFAT and reads NTFS, writing is not recommended. Commercial drivers are available and an outdated open source MacFUSE/OSXFUSE driver. Newer cameras often support exFAT.

Comment: @Archimedix - yeah, personally, I'd live with the upper case if it doesn't want to see ExFAT straight out of the box, especially for a TV, which are rarely at the cutting-edge of technology re file types & media. My own TV's 'media & net savvy' is so poor I just hang a spare PC off the HDMI & use VLC ;)

Comment: @Arshia I would just ignore it. Yes, it is annoying, but I would ignore. You make Tetsujin to have a ton of work for you. And most likely none of those will work on your TV. If you specify the model, I can find the manual

Comment: I wouldn't call exFAT more portable nor NTFS Windows-only. Both formats will work with Linux and MacOS PCs, although you may need additional drivers. Samsung TVs are more likely to support NTFS than exFAT.

Comment: @Arshia, If your TV supports SDXC then it has a high chance supporting exFAT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDXC

Answer (score 3):

maybe it would help :

1. open notepad
2. copy :

   [autorun]

   label=yOurLabeL
3. save as autorun.inf into root of your flash disk
4. eject and plug your flash disk, viola..

Comment: That's a very musical answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use Kali Linux, which has a utility tool called "disks". It's like disk management on windows. And all I do is format the USB drive to Fat32 and label it; Test.  That's it!